# Need help positioning these divs...

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm making a "get a link from the site box" but I can't seem to position these divs correctly. For the most part they are correct but I would like the title dead in the center, the "get a link" button to line up with the search box and for the search box to be more to the right. I've been fiddling with these for about 45 minutes and researching positioning on w3 but I just can't get it. Any pointers will be helpful.

Heres the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/j6pf08kn/1/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="top_con">
        <div id="title_con">
            <a href="swfs/welcomeflash.swf" id="downLink" download="welcomeflash">
                <header id="title">
                    Diff Lirl
                </header>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="share_con">
            <button id="share">Get a link!</button>
            <textarea id="link"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#top_con {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#share_con {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#link {
    width: 50%;
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

#share {}

#title_con {
    width: 57%;
    float: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#title {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Checking this out. Quick question: How do you want the vertical alignment for each of the elements with eachother? Same Height? Middles? Bottoms?

Comment: I would like them to be the same height and to align them horizontally in an ideal position I've just always been bad at deciding where to put stuff and then when I try I suck at css positioning

Comment: Almost done. Sorry, had to step away from the desk. Don't delete the question!

Comment: I won't Imma keep it up forever to help anyone in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxGepy

So I've done a few things. Listing them out now:

- I threw in another wrapper.
- I took the liberty of replacing your IDs with classes
- I have commented code in there to show you box-shadows. I like them instead of borders because of `box-sizing` and the effects borders have on the box model.
- I changed the colors because my eyes hurt.
- **I took advantage of several properties here, most notably** `float:left;`, `text-align:center;`, and `display:inline-block;`
- *Note: This does have a rather ugly breakdown when the screen sizes get much smaller. Responsiveness was not in the initial question or scope.* (Can add if requested)

---

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4) inset, 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.top_con {
  text-align: center;
}

.inner_con {
  display: inline-block;
}

.share_con {
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.share_con,
.title_con {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

.hide_my_ass {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.share {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.link {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

```
<body>
  <div class="top_con">
    <div class="inner_con">
      <div class="share_con hide_my_ass">
        <button class="share">Get a link!</button>
        <textarea class="link"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="title_con">
        <a href="#" class="downLink">
          <header class="title">
            Diff Lirl
          </header>
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class="share_con">
        <button class="share">Get a link!</button>
        <textarea class="link"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow you did a lot! Thanks for the help I really really need to get this kind of thing down if I want to improve though. Anyway I send my thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Button default has `display: inline-block`, this causes the button to drop and not align with the other elements, I have set it to `display: block` in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j6pf08kn/2/

I also have given the button the same margin-top as the textarea, the textarea itself has `float: right` with `margin-right: 10%`, you can customize it like your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, reference the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/j6pf08kn/4/

Did a lot of code refactoring: I'd recommend you study on how `float` and the different `display` properties work.

Comment: That actually looks really good! But it wouldn't go well with the rest of the site I've built. I appreciate the effort though :D

Comment: No problem! Could see the rest of the site, but I hope you found what you're looking for! Good luck buddy